# "Attachment layout" of action is simply ignored! Why?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, action

I publish an OG action/object but the attachment layout of the action (which has been set to "Item") is simply ignored. On my timeline, I click on the date/time link to see the action in full details (along with the attachment)... but all I see is a box with object image in the center and the object title at the bottom:

```
------------------
|                |
|                |
|     Image      |
|                |
|                |
------------------
|  Object Title  |
------------------
```

Instead I expect to see a smaller image at the left side along with the title and other captions on the right side (like what "Item" layout preview is showing):

```
-----------------------------------------
|         |    Object Title             |
|         | Caption 1                   |
|  Image  | Caption 2                   |
|         | Caption 3                   |
|         | Caption 4                   |
-----------------------------------------
```

And the OG tags of my object page, hosted on my website, are correct (at least the Facebook OG Debugger says so!).

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Thank you,